# Console app unable to load Program.cs or <Project_Name>.csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

For my console app, I am getting the error

> Assets file 'D:\Folder Name\Tool Name\Tool Name\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.    Tool Name   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    208

The issue with this is that the `<Folder Name>` path in actuality is "D:\ProductName%20Utilities", but the solution seems to be looking for "D:\ProductName Utilities" instead. Is there a way to change the solution to look for a the correct filepath?

Comment: Your problem is not clear at all, please add more details and/or some code

Comment: `%20` is the URL encoding for a single space. The error you posted doesn't contain that path anyway

Comment: when attempting to run a nuget or dotnet restore as suggested by the error, it says the project is unable to access the files located in the "ProductName Utilities", then lists the error as coming from "ProductName%20Utilities\ToolName\ToolName.sln"

Comment: [This is a known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/2178) that hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this by creating a folder named `ProductName%20Utilities`, creating a new project with `dotnet new console` and trying to run `dotnet build`.

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/2178) that hasn't been fixed yet.